# editable rails mail template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I'm trying to do an editable template for Rails but I can't figure it out. Basically what I'm trying to do is a normal action mailer view but before I send it I want to be able to edit its content.

So to summarize lets say I have a `report_user.html.rb` view in the mailer folder (with my default template inside) and when I click on a report button, a new page will appear with a text area with an editor. In this editor I want to have the mail body of my default template, make changes, and after I click on send, it sends with the new changes that will fit the rest of my template.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this what you want.

**1. No default template**

Get the email body from the user a string and pass it to the method that sends the email.

`class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome_email(user, email_body)
    mail(to: user.email,
         body: email_body,
         content_type: "text/html",
         subject: "Already rendered!")
  end
end`

**2. With Email template**

**report_user.html.rb**

`<html>
   <body>$body_content<body>
</html>`

get the template and replace $body_content with your params[:body]

Hope that works

Comment: yes, yours and Adilbiy Kanzitdinov helped a lot! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a standard Rails form. If you just have one email, you can save the default text in the Rails code, otherwise you can save email templates in a model for that. Load up the default content in the form when the page loads, and then send the email when you click Send.

(If you want to use Markdown, use a gem like [Redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) to process the text before sending it.)

Comment: How to I load the content of the mailer view?

Comment: You might want to save the default text in a different way. Use `value=someText` to set a default value for a form field.

Comment: Well that's exactly my problem.How to save the default text so I can edit it and them put it in the mailer view. Because lets imagine that I put some bold tags like * * on my text field. How will I be sure that it will be rendered as expected in the e-mail?

Comment: That's a different question, but you can use `.html_safe` to keep HTML from a form. If this answered the question, accept it and ask other questions separately.

Comment: You didn't ask about formatting like `* *` in your OP.  What you're talking about is `Markdown` - google "markdown rails" for how to set this up.  I think what you need to do is to create a model to hold your custom blocks of text, or add custom_text to one of your existing models.  This is what is edited by the user.  Then when you come to send the email you convert the custom_text with markdown into some html, and insert that into your standard template.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have controller action that corresponds to send action in report page.

To load the body of your mail in the text field, you either can use instance of template model, where the template model has field called body and it contains source code of your mail template, or use static text to be preloaded in text form.

This way you can edit the content of the text field and submit it to controller. In controller action responsible for report submit action you can access all submitted data in `params` hash.

Either create new template instance and pass it to Mailer action or pass whole body of text form as parameter (not recommended).

Embed the body of template object you passed inside the mailer action view. 
My solution would be as follows (some code is missed for brevity)

In controller :

```
class ReportsController < ActiveController 
  def submit
      new_template = Template.create(params[:template])
      UserMailer.send_report(user_id, new_template.id)
  end
end
```

In mailer:

```
  def send_report(user_id, template_id)
     @user = User.find(user_id)
     @template = Template.find(template_id)
     mail to: @user.email
  end
```

In template:

```
<%= @template.body %>
```